# What does "world's side" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The weird thing about the tunnel is that on the **world-side**, the city’s
> skyline is merely one incident among many on the horizon. From the
> **world’s side** of the tunnel the skyline is a row of broken teeth, an
> angry serration gnawing at the atmosphere, but there’s a lot of other
> stuff going on, dirty water and more land beyond that dirty water, the
> humble metropolitan outpost just departed, a crop of weedy
> smokestacks, lots of stuff, 360 degrees to choose from and the
> generous illusion of choice. Then the tunnel, and no more sky. Nothing
> but teeth.

This is from Colson Whitehead's *The Intuitionist*. I wonder what the world-side/world's side of the tunnel means here. Is it a side where before you enter the tunnel?

Comment: The tunnel must connect a big city of tall buildings (the city side) with the outside world. From outside, you see the skyline. That's the world view from that side, the world side.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I agree. From the world's side you see the city, from the city's side you see the world. The fact that the author is implying that the city is not part of the world probably makes sense in the context of the work.